# Как сделать до 576px мобильную версию, а после 576 pc?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите как применить(meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0") до 576px, а 576< не применять, чтобы была pc версия. Конкретнее, надо чтобы до 576 ширина сайта = ширина устройства, а 577+ ширина сайта 1920px. Мне говорят что применять мета тег на определенной ширине, а на определенной не применять колхоз. подскажите, Может есть другие способы решения проблемы?

Comment: А чем не подходят media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант из [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp):

> There are tons of screens and devices with different heights and widths, so it is hard to create an exact breakpoint for each device. To keep things simple you could target five groups:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Либо использовать готовые вещи, например [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), где все уже давно продумано.

Comment: Так если у меня некоторые блоки с шириной в vw, то мне прийдется для каждого прописывать

Comment: я бы сделал что-то типо [такого](https://jsfiddle.net/bogdan_017/jrug4yn9/) (чтобы увидеть разницу, нужно сделать resize для окна просморта)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize > 576) {
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute("content", "width=1920, initial-scale=0,maximum-scale=0");
    }  else {
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute("content", "width=device-width,  initial-scale=0");
    }
    }
    checkWidth();
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
```